# How to typeset multiple equations center aligned but with single eq. number?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, ieeetran

I want to typeset several equations with only one equation number vertically centered, and every equation horizontally center.

I know two options. One is `aligned` environment within `equation`, which handles equation number nicely, but the default alignment (without any `&`) is right alignment; and you know, you can't rely on `&` to force center alignment.

Another is `IEEEeqnarray` environment, which handles alignment nicely, but the equation numbering of which is somewhat awkward since numbering is processed on a line-to-line basis, as far as I know (if the number of equations is even, or equations take different vertical space, you will be screwed).

Any idea about this? Maybe I missed some functionality of `aligned` or `IEEEeqnarray`?

Comment: Have you tried `gathered`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the package `mathtools` provides the `gathered` environment, which behaves like `aligned` (in that there is only one equation number generated), but otherwise behaves like `amsmath`'s `gather` (in centering every line separately).

`mathtools` loads `amsmath` automatically, and options to `amsmath` can be passed via specifying those options to `mathtools`.

Comment: As far as I know, `gathered` is already in `amsmath`

Comment: @egreg Yes, it is. Most of time I work in `amsart`, which means I don't need extra package at all.

Comment: @egreg -- aarrrggghhhh.  i really ought to check the documentation before answering.  i knew (at least) one of the "ed" forms was missing, and i mis-guessed.  (there isn't any `multlined` in `amsmath`, but it's there in `mathtools`.)